# Moq MockRepository from Interface

Tags: c#, interface, moq

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a MockRepository that implements a repository interface. Currently, this is what I have:

```
public class MockUserRepository
    {
        private readonly IList<User> _users;

        public MockUserRepository()
        {
            _users = new List<User>()
                         {
                             new User()
                                 {
                                     UserId = new Guid("E480E40F-6802-4296-B2A8-E0D5E018CD41"),
                                     Username = "admin",
                                     Password = "5A105E8B9D40E1329780D62EA2265D8A",
                                     CellPhone = "3175172957"
                                 }
                         };
        }

        public IUserRepository Create()
        {
            var mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();

            mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.Count()).Returns(_users.Count());

            mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.Get()).Returns(_users);

            mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns((Guid id) => _users.First(x => x.UserId == id));

            mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.Save(It.IsAny<User>())).Returns(
                (User user) =>
                    {
                        var now = DateTime.Now;

                        user.ModifiedOn = now;

                        if(user.UserId.Equals(Guid.Empty))
                        {
                            user.CreatedOn = now;
                            _users.Add(user);
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            var original = _users.First(x => x.UserId == user.UserId);
                            if (original == null)
                            {
                                return false;
                            }

                            original = user;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                );

            mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<IList<object[]>>())).Returns(
                (IList<object[]> criteria) =>
                {
                    IList<User> uList = _users.ToList();

                    foreach (object[] criteriaItem in criteria)
                    {
                        var name = (string)criteriaItem[0];
                        var value = (string)criteriaItem[1];
                        IList<User> tempList = uList.ToList();
                        IList<User> addList = tempList.Where(user => (string) user.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(user, null) == value).ToList();
                        uList = addList;
                    }
                    return uList;
                });

            return mockUserRepository.Object;
        }
    }
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
public class MockUserRepository : IUserRepository
```

Then, just have all of my mocked methods actually implemented. I want to do this to enforce my developers to fully mock out a repository based on the interface.

From the test side, this Mocked Repository is used like this:

```
[SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        MockUserRepository = new MockUserRepository().Create();
        MockRoleRepository = new MockRoleRepository().Create();
        MockQuestionRepository = new MockQuestionRepository().Create();

        AuthenticationService = new AuthenticationService(MockUserRepository, MockRoleRepository, MockQuestionRepository);
    }
```

All of this works just fine, but I'm really stuck on enforcing my MockRepository to implement all of its interface's methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is over-complicating the use of mocks. simply Mock the IUserRepository interface in the test and then mock the methods you need based on the tests.

```
reposistory = new Mock<IUserRepository>();

var id = 1;
var user = new User();
repository.Setup(x=> x.Get(id)).Returns(user);

var sut = new Service(repository.Object);
var result = sut.Get(id);

Assert.Equals(user, result);
```

If you really want a "blank" object just implement a Fake IUserRepository and forgo a mocking framework altogether.

```
class FakeUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public List<User> Users = new List<Users>();

    public User Get(long id)
    {
         return Users.FristOrDetail(x=>x.Id = id);
    }
}

var id = 1;
var user = new User();
var repository = new FakeUserRepository();
repository.Users.Add(user);

var sut = new Service(repository);
var result = sut.Get(id);

Assert.Equals(user, result);
```

Comment: Am I really over-complicating it? I'm considering that I will have at least 10 services, each service will use 1 or more repositories, and most repositories will be used by several services. For example, AuthenticationService and say EventService might use the UserRepository. In your example, I would be writing the same Setup many times. Now, as you should know, I'm a programmer, therefore I'm lazy. Why wouldn't I want to just write my Setups once? And I'm still curious about enforcing my developers to implement all of the repository interface's methods.

Comment: what you want is a stub, not a fake. implement a concrete class and provide hooks for getting and setting the values you want. I'll update my answer with a simple fake

Comment: You have helped me see the light! I was over-complicating everything. I've decided against using Moq for now and instead I'm just going to create FakeRepositories. I might return back to Moq at some point in the future, but for now, faking will work for me. Thanks!